# How to emulate an async Filestream

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, filestream

I'm working on a program and I'm getting some glitches in my graphical display.

To troubleshoot the display glitch I'm trying to emulate a filestream output instead of having an actual controller connected to the pc and push random numbers. I'm struggling to emulate an async filestream without breaking the flow of the application.

```
if (fileStreamDeviceData.CanRead)
{
    try
    {
        readTrigger = true;
        while (readTrigger)
        {
            await fileStreamDeviceData.ReadAsync(outputReportBuffer, 0, 
                outputReportBuffer.Length);

            msgQue.Enqueue(outputReportBuffer);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

This part is the one i asume needs changing. Its part of an async method and this part takes the `outputReportBuffer` from the filestream object and adds it to the que.

This is what i need to reproduce basically. Here is what i changed and tryed but this is freezing the thread. so i assume i have to create a new thread to create random numbers or is there a simpler way?

```
Random rdm = new Random();
readTrigger = true;
while (readTrigger)
{
      await fileStreamDeviceData.ReadAsync(outputReportBuffer, 0, 
          outputReportBuffer.Length);

      for (int a = 0; a < outputReportBuffer.Length; a++)
      {
           outputReportBuffer[a] = (Byte)rdm.Next(0, 255);
      }

      msgQue.Enqueue(outputReportBuffer);
}
```

I've looked around and have not found a solid solution to emulating the async filestream effectively.
Any pointer or advice for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the buffer really long enough to cause a lot of latency when filling that? If yes, run this part of the method on the thread-pool using await Task.Run.

Comment: great idea. ill attempt that

Answer (score 0):

When using `await` from the GUI thread, the remainder of the method after the `await` is also executed on the GUI thread. If that is expensive, your display may become unresponsive. You can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to request that the remainder of the method be executed on the thread pool, that may help you application.

```
await fileStreamDeviceData.ReadAsync(outputReportBuffer, 0, 
      outputReportBuffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The best thing might be to use a profiler to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: The responsiveness we solved by just queing up all output and then having mutliple threads handle the conversion and the display. That part is working rather well. Its the actual graphics component that is glitching and im trying to recreate the issue without the controler for the sake of reporting it. I cant send my hardware to the company we got the component from...

Answer (score 0):

Is the buffer really long enough to cause a lot of latency when filling that? If yes, run this part of the method on the thread-pool using await Task.Run.

I recommend not to use `ConfigureAwait` to move to the thread-pool. It becomes not obvious what runs on the UI thread and what on the pool because the same code now runs once on the UI thread and in later iterations on the thread-pool. Confusing.